# Click UIView Pass data and set as Navigationitem title from UIView Data in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have Many views in firstVC and the view have 3 object if i select any one views in the view data set as navigationItem title to the secondVC.

```
     firstVC:
        //UIView set Action

            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
            View1.tag = 1;
            [View1 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap1];


            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
            view2.tag = 2;
            [view2 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap2];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
            view3.tag = 3;
            [view3 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap3];

            }

        -(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
        {

            UIView *viewClicked = sender.view;
            NSLog(@"Clicked: %ld",(long)viewClicked.tag);

             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];


        }

        -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
        {
            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Segue"])
            {
                DetailsViewController *controller = (DetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
                controller = [segue destinationViewController];
                controller.DataValue = arrayValue;

            }
        }
```

its pass data correctly but cant set navigationItem title each and every view while clicked.

secondVC:
    and another help there is 20 element (like 20 `index[0]` to `[20]`) i don't want write code for each index like below, i don't know how to wrote code in `objectAtIndex:some` (not 0 to 20)

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
        NSDictionary *dictValue = [DataValue objectAtIndex:0];
        self.navigationItem.title = [dictValue valueForKey:@"code"];
    // NSDictionary *dictValue1 = [DataValue objectAtIndex:1];
    //   self.navigationItem.title = [dictValue1 valueForKey:@"code"];
    //    NSDictionary *dictValue2 = [DataValue objectAtIndex:2];
    //    self.navigationItem.title = [dictValue2 valueForKey:@"code"];
}
```

Comment: is not a good pratice to work , can u add some more code related to arrayValue

Comment: in secondVC dont want to do anything, just assign is enough, in your first vc , do any modification

Comment: thank you @Anbu.Karthik:    id response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];                                                                                 arrayValue = [response valueForKey:@"docs"];

Comment: ok are you tried my answer, we dont know whats ur project contains

Comment: in my probelm what mention in objectAtIndex:@"____"; in viewWillAppear

Comment: can you print the `DataValue`

Comment: yes  i printed in my viewDidLoad then only assigned values.

Comment: balaji, no need to identify the each index on second VC, on your first VC, you need to short out based on click  or else and send the single index to second vc

Comment: Thank@Anbu your right i done the same now.